# Nginx configuration does not work

Tags: linux, nginx, dns, debian, webserver

I have created few subdomains for my domain like api.example.com, dev.example.com and www.example.com. For every subdomain I created an virtualhost in Nginx.

But now the problem is when I visit a domain which does not exist it should be redirected to www.example.com. But this is not the exist instead I am getting an error page that the sub domain does not have an secure connection. Since I am using Let's Encrypt, I get this message all the time for sub domains which is incorrect. I contacted my DNS provider and they told me your settings are correct you have to correct your web server configuration. They added a CNAME.

Now I do not know how to add this in my nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

So... you type the https ://incorrect.example.com in your browser?
If so, I think the problem cannot be solved.
In the article (https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/can-i-use-letsencrypt-in-more-than-one-subdomain/16588/8) they said

> Let's Encrypt does not currently offer "wildcard" certificates. So you will need to be able to list all the domains you want a certificate for, you can't (as you can with some of the pricier paid certificates) get just one that works for every possible name in your domain. With Let's Encrypt you'd need to issue new certificates for any new names you needed.

That showed you can't set all the certificate of incorrect subdomains...

But if you just type "http ://incorrect.example.com", It can be success redirect without error page.
If error page continue occurring, please post your conf of nginx.

Comment: No, this is not the problem. The incorrect sub domains should be redirected to www.example.com. But all incorrect sub domains like catch all adress. @wildfoot

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is "all incorrect sub domains like catch all adress" means... 
My English is pretty limited now.. Can you put the sentence another way?

Answer (score 0):

I see two separate questions -

1. security warning can be removed using a wildcard certificate from letsencrypt. Please see detailed instructions [here](https://www.avantinsights.com/certbot-wildcard-ssl/)
2. Redirect non-existent domains to www.domainname.com
   You need multiple server sections in place -

   - Have server {} sections for each existent domain to port 443 (HTTPS port)
   - Have one server {} section for *.domainname.com to redirect to port 443 or www.domainname.com
   - If you are running an app that dynamically uses subdomains (for each customer) the app should also implement the redirection to www.domainname.com for non-existent subdomains.